# Want to concatenate multiple row data in in cell along with its values if present. Emp Id should not come if no data available infromt of it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have data in below format

[image]

And Expecting output in below format

[image]

Comment: If you have Office 365 Excel then use TEXTJOIN, otherwise it is vba.  What have you tried?  Stack Overflow is not a code for me service.

Comment: Please provide examples of approaches you've tried so far.

Comment: And how do you expect excel to do it for you?

Comment: Scott Craner- I tried in excel using some concatenate formulas but it doesn't work. Could you please let me know how to do it in VBA

Comment: Zerk- I tried with some if and concatenate formulas. But it doesn't work for me. Could you please help with VBA

Answer (score 0):

Using TEXTJOIN would be the easiest way, but if you wanted you can also use a VBA code.

```
Function Concat(rng As Range, Optional sep As String = " / ") As String
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim strResult As String
    For Each rngCell In rng
        If rngCell.Value <> "" Then
            strResult = strResult & sep & rngCell.Value
        End If
    Next rngCell
    If strResult <> "" Then
        strResult = Mid(strResult, Len(sep) + 1)
    End If
    Concat = strResult
End Function
```

In your case, you can use column F as a helper range and enter =Concat(A7:E7) in cell F2. This will generate the appropriate list back fitting your needs, minus the "-" between the EMP ID and the values. You can play around with the code to fix that if you desire, but this code will work for you.